# Как работать с асинхронными сигналами (камера - внешняя память)

Tags: verilog

**Verilog-2001, QuartusII 13.0**.
Необходимо с камеры записать информацию во внешнюю sram память.

---

Имеются модули: **CameraGrab** *(Захват данных с камеры)*, **SRAM_Module** *(Запись/чтение SRAM)*, **MainController** *(Контроллер)*, **Main** *(Модуль верхнего уровня)*.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Для примера убрал все лишнее из модулей, что бы не нагромождать, постарался оставить так, что бы было понятно что примерно каждый из модулей делает:
Модуль верхнего уровня **Main:**

```
module Main(
input wire clk_24MHz,
input wire clk_100MHz,
output wire [7:0] o_SramData8OUT,
output wire o_DataValid
);

wire w_CamValidPix;
wire [7:0] w_camData8;

wire w_SramEn;
wire [7:0] w_SramData8;
wire w_SramBusy;
wire w_SramDone;

MainController MC(
.clk_24MHz(clk_24MHz),
.clk_100MHz(clk_100MHz),
.i_CamValidPix(w_CamValidPix),
.i_camData8(w_camData8),
.i_SramBusy(w_SramBusy),
.i_SramDone(w_SramDone),
.o_SramEn(w_SramEn),
.o_SramData8(w_SramData8)
);

SRAM_Module SM(
.clk_100MHz(clk_100MHz),
.i_SramEn(w_SramEn),
.i_SramData8(w_SramData8),
.o_SramBusy(w_SramBusy),
.o_SramDone(w_SramDone),
.o_SramData8OUT(o_SramData8OUT),
.o_DataValid(o_DataValid)
);

CameraGrab CG(
.clk_24MHz(clk_24MHz),
.o_CamValidPix(w_CamValidPix),
.or_camData8(w_camData8)
);

endmodule
```

Модуль контроллера (обработчика). Суть вопроса именно в нем **MainController:**

```
module MainController (
input wire clk_24MHz,
input wire clk_100MHz,
input wire i_CamValidPix,
input wire [7:0] i_camData8,

input wire i_SramBusy,
input wire i_SramDone,

output reg o_SramEn,
output wire [7:0] o_SramData8
);

//здесь главный вопрос...
//по сигналу i_CamValidPix надо передать один раз данные в SRAM_Module
//т.е. разрешить передачу байта и вовремя запретить, что бы не передать его дважды
always @ (posedge i_CamValidPix) begin
    if (!i_SramBusy && i_CamValidPix) o_SramEn <= 1'd1; //разрешаем передачу...
    //..тут не понимаю как быть дальше. надо o_SramEn как-то отключить как только модуль SRAM_Module его принял в работу
end

//передаем байт в модуль SRAM_Module непрерывно как есть
assign o_SramData8 = i_camData8;

endmodule
```

Модуль захвата с камеры **CameraGrab:**

```
module CameraGrab (
input wire clk_24MHz,
output wire o_CamValidPix,
output reg [7:0] or_camData8
);

reg r_change = 1'd0;

//для примера - меняем выходные данные при каждом клоке
always @ (posedge clk_24MHz) begin
    r_change <= !r_change;
    if (r_change) or_camData8 <= 8'd0;
    else or_camData8 <= 8'd255;
end

//как пример валидности данных -  просто выводим входной клок
assign o_CamValidPix = clk_24MHz;

endmodule
```

Модуль записи во внешнюю память **SRAM_Module:**

```
module SRAM_Module (
input wire clk_100MHz,
input wire i_SramEn,
input wire [7:0] i_SramData8,
output reg o_SramBusy = 1'd0,
output reg o_SramDone = 1'd0,
output reg [7:0] o_SramData8OUT,
output reg o_DataValid
);

reg [3:0] state = 4'd0;

always @ (posedge clk_100MHz) begin
    case (state)
        4'd0: begin
            o_SramDone <= 1'd0;     //не закончено
            //если сигнал разрешения
            if (i_SramEn) begin
                o_SramBusy <= 1'd1; //занят
                //отправляем полученные от модуля камеры данные наружу
                o_SramData8OUT <= i_SramData8;
                o_DataValid <= 1'd1;
                state <= 4'd1;          //переход
            end
            else begin
                state <= 4'd0;          //остаемся здесь
            end
        end
        
        4'd1: begin
            //что-то еще делаем
            o_DataValid <= 1'd0;
            state <= 4'd2;              //переход
        end
        
        4'd2: begin
            o_SramBusy <= 1'd0;     //свободен
            o_SramDone <= 1'd1;     //закончено
            state <= 4'd0;              //переход в начало
        end
        
        default: begin
            state <= 4'd0;
        end
    endcase
end

endmodule
```

**CameraGrab** на частоте 24МГц принимает байты с физического устройства и передает в **MainController** сигнал валидности данных, т.е. по фронту этого сигнала можно записывать байт в память. **SRAM_Module** работает на частоте 100МГц и за 3 такта производит запись в микросхему SRAM.

---

Не могу понять как в модуле обработчика **MainController** правильно передать байт с камеры по сигналу валидности (фронт сигнала от **CameraGrab**) в **SRAM_Module**.  *Возможно, надо как-то экранировать и сбрасывать сигнал готовности данных (что бы не писать одни и те же данные дважды). Но как это сделать, что бы не трогать сам входной сигнал, а оперировать экранированным? По сути надо поймать сигнал готовности данных (24МГц) и по его фронту один раз запустить конечный автомат (100МГц), далее снова ожидать фронт сигнала готовности данных...*

---

Желательно без использования fifo и других буферов, ведь камера передает данные на гораздо меньшей частоте и мы успеваем записать данные в память до того как придет следующий валидный байт. Я новичок, прошу направить в правильное русло.

Comment: ничего не понятно

Comment: @PavelGridin Модуль контролера управляет 2-мя модулями (чтение байта из камеры и запись этого байта во внешнюю микросхему SRAM). Когда камера готова передать байт, в модуль контролера приходит фронт сигнала _i_mcCamValidPixCLK _ о том, что байт (шина 8бит от камеры) можно записать в SRAM. Камера передает данные на частоте 24МГц, а модуль SRAM работает на 100МГц, запись байта в память происходит за 3 такта. Т.е. модуль контроллера во время фронта сигнала от модуля камеры _i_mcCamValidPixCLK _ должен взять по шине от камеры 1 байт и передать его в модуль SRAM для записи этого байта

Comment: Если делать как-то так:
`always @ (posedge mcClk_100 or posedge i_mcCamValidPixCLK or negedge nRST) begin
 if (i_mcCamValidPixCLK) //сигнал на запись байта в модуль записи во внешнюю память
  //разрешаем запись байта во внешнюю память
end`
то есть большая вероятность, что один и тот же байт запишется в память более 1-го раза. Надо по сигналу от модуля камеры передать байт только 1 раз в модуль записи памяти

Comment: Добавил код модулей, постарался сделать вопрос более понятным. Главный вопрос в модуле **MainController**, который должен объединить модули **CameraGrab** и **SRAM_Module**.

Comment: @Faust, имеет смысл задать вопрос на английском SO, здесь мало людей кто по HDL отвечает.

Comment: @eanmos, спасибо за совет. если не дождусь ответа, задам вопрос на английском

Comment: или спросить на electronix.ru, я только vhdl знаю

Comment: всем спасибо за советы, кажется, разобрался, ответ добавил. если в ответе что-то не так, буду рад любой полезной критике

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методом проб и ошибок получилось. В модуле **MainController** использовал в списке чувствительности в блоке *always* сигнал *i_SramBusy* в качестве обратной связи от модуля **SRAM_Module**

```
//по сигналу i_CamValidPix надо передать один раз данные в SRAM_Module
//т.е. разрешить передачу байта и вовремя запретить, что бы не передать его дважды
always @ (posedge i_CamValidPix or posedge i_SramBusy) begin
    if (i_SramBusy) o_SramEn <= 1'd0;
    else if (!i_SramBusy) o_SramEn <= 1'd1;
end

//передаем байт в модуль SRAM_Module непрерывно как есть
assign o_SramData8 = i_camData8;
```

Симуляция *Waveform* показала следующую картину, которая выглядит корректно:
[image: Сигнал o_SramDone выведен для отладки, остальное без изменений]

На следующем изображении для проверки изменил вывод из модуля камеры **CameraGrab** и в модуле верхнего уровня **Main**, так что бы сигнал валидности данных стал входным, а не просто выводил клок 24МГц. Теперь я рисую сигнал i_pixValidDebug в *Waveform*, и снова выходные сигналы такие как должны быть:
[image: Сигнал o_SramDone выведен для отладки, добавлен входной отладочный сигнал i_pixValidDebug]

Если где-то ошибаюсь, поправьте пожалуйста. Надеюсь использовать это для реального проекта.